# How to Optimize a Query With GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have got a `POSTS` table, the structure is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` longtext COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci,
  `excerpt` longtext COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci,
  `link` longtext COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci,
  `original_link` longtext COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci,
  `mime_type` longtext COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci,
  `language_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_deleted` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=52487 ;
```

And a USERS table, structed like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=9422 ;
```

I'm using this query to get latest "page, file or post" posts ordered by descending time and grouping by user to not show all latest posts from a user:

```
   SELECT p.*, u.* 
     FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.id 
    WHERE p.type IN ('post', 'page', 'file') 
 GROUP BY p.user_id 
 ORDER BY p.created_at DESC 
    LIMIT 30
```

But it is too slow, even limited to 30 records.

now, how can i speed up this query? which columns to index or any other ideas? thanks.

Comment: Users table has over 9000 users and posts table has over 50,000 posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to do is to add an  index on `posts.user_id` (or maybe `posts.user_id + posts.type`). And another index on `posts.created_at`

**UPDATE**
I've just payed attention that your query grabs all fields from both tables, and posts table has 6 long text columns. So I believe you have a poor performance because mysql has to create quite a large temporary table or temp file to get all rows for satisfying your `group by` + `order by` clauses. 
I think the following query should help.

```
  SELECT u.*, p1.* FROM
  users u 
  INNER JOIN 
  (
      SELECT p.user_id, p.created_at, p.id FROM posts p 
      WHERE  p.type IN ('post', 'page', 'file')  GROUP by p.user_id 
      ORDER BY p.created_at DESC LIMIT 30
  )xxx ON xxx.user_id = u.id
   INNER JOIN posts p1 ON (p1.id = xxx.id)
```

Comment: That was my call too, but the OP updated the CREATE TABLE to show that user_id is indexed :/

Comment: Yes i created indexes for every column mentioned in query but nothing changed :(

Comment: It work like a charm. The query now tooks just 3 seconds (i know it's still far away then best)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of indices, I would suggest creating ones on posts.type (WHERE), posts.created_at (ORDER). That should help speed up the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

SELECT p.*, u.*
     FROM (SELECT * FROM posts WHERE p.type IN ('post', 'page', 'file')) p
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.id
    GROUP BY p.user_id   ORDER BY p.created_at DESC
    LIMIT 30

MySQL first proccess the inner query, and with its result process the outter query with less records.

Comment: The query still takes 7 seconds. no gain.

Answer (score 0):

Try @Gabriel's answer, but with the LIMIT in the inner query.

SELECT p.*, u.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM posts WHERE type IN ('post', 'page', 'file') ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 30) p
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY p.created_at;